# С какой буквы пишется слово "заочье"?

Tags: прописная-строчная

С какой буквы пишется слово **заочье** (Ока)?

Comment: @Верьясова, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

Нужна прописная. Здесь название.